# Can not get flyway-docker to recognize local files in volumes

Tags: flyway

I am trying to use Flyway to set up a DB2 test/demo environment in a Docker container.  I have an image of DB2 running in a docker container and now am trying to get flyway to create the database environment.  I can connect to the DB2 docker container and create DB2 objects and load them with data, but am looking for a way for non-technical users to do this (i.e. clone a GitHub repo and issue a single docker run command).

The Flyway Docker site (https://github.com/flyway/flyway-docker) indicates that it supports the following volumes:

```
| Volume            | Description                                            |
|-------------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
| `/flyway/conf`    | Directory containing a flyway.conf                     |
| `/flyway/drivers` | Directory containing the JDBC driver for your database |
| `/flyway/sql`     | The SQL files that you want Flyway to use              |
```

I created the `conf`, `drivers`, and `sql` directories.  In the `conf` directory, I placed the file `flyway.conf` that contained my flyway Url, user name, and password:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/apidemo
flyway.user=DB2INST1
flyway.passord=mY%tEst%pAsSwOrD
```

In the `drivers` directory, I added the DB2 JDBC Type 4 drivers (e.g. `db2jcc4.jar`, `db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar`),

And in the `sql` directory I put in a simple table creation statement (file name: `V1__make_temp_table.sql`):

```
CREATE TABLE EDS.REFT_TEMP_DIM (
      TEMP_ID       INTEGER  NOT NULL )
  ,   TEMP_CD       CHAR    (8)
  ,   TEMP_NM       VARCHAR (255)
  )
  DATA CAPTURE NONE 
  COMPRESS NO;
```

Attempting to perform the docker `run` with the `flyway/flyway` image as described in the GitHub `Readme.md`, it is not recognizing the `flyway.conf` file, since it does not know the url, user, and password.

```
docker run --rm -v sql:/flyway/sql -v conf:/flyway/conf -v drivers:/flyway/drivers flyway/flyway migrate


Flyway Community Edition 6.5.5 by Redgate
ERROR: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!
```

I then put the url, user, and password inline and It could not find the JDBC driver.

```
docker run --rm -v sql:/flyway/sql -v drivers:/flyway/drivers flyway/flyway -url=jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/apidemo -user=DB2INST1 -password=mY%tEst%pAsSwOrD migrate

ERROR: Unable to instantiate JDBC driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver => Check whether the jar file is present
Caused by: Unable to instantiate class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver : com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

Therefore, I believe it is the way that I am setting up the local file system or associating to local files with the flyway volumes that is causing the issue. Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply absolute paths to your volumes for docker to mount them.

Changing the relative paths to absolute paths fixed the volume mount issue.

```
docker run --rm \
-v /Users/steve/github-ibm/flyway-db-migration/sql:/flyway/sql \
-v /Users/steve/github-ibm/flyway-db-migration/conf:/flyway/conf \
-v /Users/steve/github-ibm/flyway-db-migration/drivers:/flyway/drivers \
flyway/flyway migrate
```